# How can an exception class obtain the object that raised it?

Tags: ruby, exception, binding

I want one of my exception classes to be able to obtain the object in whose context the exception was raised.  For example, in the semi-pseudocode

```
class Foo
  def zorch!
    raise MyException.new("d'oh!")
  end
end

c = Foo.new
c.zorch!
```

I want `MyException#initialize` to be able to obtain the object `c`.

This can probably be done somehow using `self.send(:binding)` in the `#initialize` method, but I haven't figured out how yet:

```
Kernel.eval('self', self.send(:binding)).class.name
=> MyException   # *not* 'Foo'
```

Which makes sense, since MyException hasn't been fully instantiated yet and `self.send(:binding)` refers to the current context rather than the caller's.

So how can I access the caller's context/binding?

Comment: did you find a better solution?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it?

Comment: I believe I wanted to know so that I could add information from the excepting object to the report I'd be generating -- but I forget exactly at this point.

I **miss** Digital's VMS's feature-rich exception handling..

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyException < StandardError
  attr_reader :obj
  def initialize obj, *args; super(*args); @obj = obj end
end

class Foo
  def zorch!
    raise MyException.new(self, "d'oh!")
  end
end

c = Foo.new
begin
  c.zorch!
rescue => e
  puts e.obj
end
# => #<Foo:0x007fdd4a474da0>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to avoid special calling sequences for this, so altering the sequence to include a reference to the caller won't do.  Thanks, though.

Comment: and what about exceptions raised by libraries and ruby itself?

Answer (score 1):

The code from http://docs.honeybadger.io/ruby/exceptions/extending-ruby-exceptions.html is the best you can get:

```
require 'binding_of_caller'

module RaiseWithObject
  attr_accessor :exc_obj

  def raise *args
    args.first.exc_obj = self if args.first
    super
  end
end

class Object
  include RaiseWithObject
end
```

It will work for most exceptions, but not for the internal ones raised inside MRI.